# Which supply items do you get to keep?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

During the tutorial stages of the games, they told me that any items I take out of the blue chest will be returned at the end of the mission.

I've noticed, however, that sometimes I keep certain items that I grabbed out of the blue chest after the mission is over. For example, I have a lot of cool drinks because I rarely visit those sections of the Sandy Plains.

Which items from the blue chest do I get to keep after the mission is over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of the Supply Items are denoted with the EZ prefix, as in, "EZ Flash Bomb" or "EZ Shock Trap".  Some items don't match this, though, and are still Supply Items, such as First Aid Meds or Rations.

The simplest way to find out is to check the items in your bag.  If the description includes `Supply Item`, you will return it after the mission is over.

The items that are given to you, and you don't return, include:

- Hot Drinks
- Cold Drinks
- Ammo (both coatings and shots)
- Antidotes
- Cleansers
- Nulberries
- Pickaxes
- Nets

In general, if you can gather it, or make it, it won't make you return it at the end of the quest.  So if you have to choose between using supply items or items that you brought yourself, use the supply items; there's no reason to hold on to them at all.